# Function with same name issue

Tags: javascript, function

I am writing code to execute two functions with the same name. I am using two different approaches:

**Method1: with storing function in `var`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <div id="demo1">I am div1.</div>
 <div id="demo2">I am div2.</div>
    <script>
  let x;
  var fun1 = function(val1, val2){
   x = val1 + val2;
   document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = x;
  }
  fun1(2, 2);
  
  var fun1 = function(val1, val2){
   x = val1 + val2;
   document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = x;
  }  
  fun1(1, 1);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Method2: using simple `function`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <div id="demo1">I am div1.</div>
 <div id="demo2">I am div2.</div>
    <script>
  let x;
  function fun1(val1, val2){
   x = val1 + val2;
   document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = x;
  }
  fun1(2, 2);
  
  function fun1(val1, val2){
   x = val1 + val2;
   document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = x;
  }  
  fun1(1, 1);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Why does `method1` execute both functions while `method2` does not.

Comment: Function overriding.

Comment: Because of [function declaration hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)

Comment: Why do you think that two different functions can have the same name?

Comment: If they want to behave differently, name them different.

Comment: @JonasW. in small application it is not considrable, but in large scale application it considerable, especially if your team member are more and fresher.

Comment: @tushar large projects arent possible in js IMO. One should use `typescript` for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions are defined with the `function` keyword.

To define a function, you can either use a function declaration (your method 2) or a function expression (your method 1).

Function declarations [hoist the definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function). You can use the function before you declare it:

```
fun1(); // logs "bar"

function fun1() {
  console.log('foo');
}

// Both function declarations are hoisted to the top
// The second declaration 'overrides' the first declaration
function fun1() {
  console.log('bar');
}
```

This also means that the second declaration of `fun1` overrides the first declaration because they are both hoisted.

However, function expressions (method 1) are not hoisted:

```
fun1(); // TypeError: fun1 is not a function

var fun1 = function() {
   console.log('foo');
}

fun1(); // logs 'foo'. the variable fun1 is hoisted, but the function is not.

var fun1 = function() {
    console.log('bar');
}

fun1(); // logs 'bar' because fun1 is now assigned to a different function.
```